# How to do constant propagation in julia?

Tags: julia

```
@noinline f1(x::Int) = x + 1
@noinline f2(x::Int) = x + 2

@Base.pure function f(x::Int, p::Int)
    if p == 1
        return f1(x)
    else
        return f2(x)
    end
end
```

I would like a call such as `f(1, 2)` to be compiled as `f2(1)` directly without branching due to `2` being a constant.

```
@code_warntype f(1, 2)
Body::Int64
│╻ ==5 1 ─ %1 = (p === 1)::Bool
│   └──      goto #3 if not %1
│ 6 2 ─ %3 = invoke Main.f1(_2::Int64)::Int64
│   └──      return %3
│ 8 3 ─ %5 = invoke Main.f2(_2::Int64)::Int64
│   └──      return %5

@code_native f(1, 2)
    .text
; Function f {
; Location: In[1]:5
; Function ==; {
; Location: In[1]:5
    pushq   %rax
    cmpq    $1, %rsi
;}
    jne L21
; Location: In[1]:6
    movabsq $julia_f1_35810, %rax
    callq   *%rax
    popq    %rcx
    retq
; Location: In[1]:8
L21:
    movabsq $julia_f2_35811, %rax
    callq   *%rax
    popq    %rcx
    retq
    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
;}
```

However by the look of the code it generates, constant propagation doesn't happen. Is it possible the constant propagation happens in real life but the monitoring tool such as `@code_native` or `@code_warntype` are unable to tell because they don't treat `2` as a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant propagation will happen if you call `f` in a compiled part of code with a constant argument (e.g. called from a function).

So in your case you have:

```
julia> @noinline f1(x::Int) = x + 1
f1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @noinline f2(x::Int) = x + 2
f2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function f(x::Int, p::Int)
           if p == 1
               return f1(x)
           else
               return f2(x)
           end
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype f(1,2)
Body::Int64
2 1 ─ %1 = (p === 1)::Bool                                                                                                                                                                     │╻ ==
  └──      goto #3 if not %1                                                                                                                                                                   │
3 2 ─ %3 = invoke Main.f1(_2::Int64)::Int64                                                                                                                                                    │
  └──      return %3                                                                                                                                                                           │
5 3 ─ %5 = invoke Main.f2(_2::Int64)::Int64                                                                                                                                                    │
  └──      return %5                                                                                                                                                                           │

julia> g() = f(1,2)
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype g()
Body::Int64
1 1 ─     return 3

julia> h(x) = f(x,2)
h (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype h(10)
Body::Int64
1 1 ─ %1 = invoke Main.f2(_2::Int64)::Int64                                                                                                                                                     │╻ f
  └──      return %1
```

As a side note, AFAIK `@pure` macro should not be used with functions that call generic functions, as is the case of `f`.

EDIT: I have found an interesting corner case here:

```
julia> f(x,p) = (p==1 ? sin : cos)(x)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype f(10, 2)
Body::Any
1 1 ─ %1 = (p === 1)::Bool                                                                                                                                                                     │╻ ==
  └──      goto #3 if not %1                                                                                                                                                                   │
  2 ─ %3 = Main.sin::Core.Compiler.Const(sin, false)                                                                                                                                           │
  └──      goto #4                                                                                                                                                                             │
  3 ─ %5 = Main.cos::Core.Compiler.Const(cos, false)                                                                                                                                           │
  4 ┄ %6 = φ (#2 => %3, #3 => %5)::Union{typeof(cos), typeof(sin)}                                                                                                                             │
  │   %7 = (%6)(x)::Any                                                                                                                                                                        │
  └──      return %7                                                                                                                                                                           │

julia> g() = f(10, 2)
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype g()
Body::Float64
1 1 ─ %1 = invoke Base.Math.cos(10.0::Float64)::Float64                                                                                                                                        │╻╷ f
  └──      return %1                                                                                                                                                                           │

julia> h(x) = f(x, 2)
h (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype h(10)
Body::Any
1 1 ─ %1 = invoke Main.f(_2::Int64, 2::Int64)::Any                                                                                                                                                 │
  └──      return %1

julia> z() = h(10)
z (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype z()
Body::Float64
1 1 ─ %1 = invoke Base.Math.cos(10.0::Float64)::Float64                                                                                                                                       │╻╷╷ h
  └──      return %1
```

The thing that is interesting is that for `g` constant propagation happens as above, but not for `h`, but then if you wrap `h` in a function it happens again.

So in general the conclusion probably is that in standard cases in compiled code you can expect constant propagation to happen, but in complex cases the compiler may not be smart enough (of course this can improve in the future).